# Different Paths To msbuild in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

OS: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]`

VS-Version: `2017 Community`

When I run `vswhere.exe` I get the following back and based on on the official `vswhere` [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/blob/develop/README.md#example)  I can build the path to `msbuild` and this seems to work:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
Visual Studio Locator version 1.0.62 [query version 1.10.80.60812]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[...]
installationPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community
[...]
C:\Users\user\Desktop>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 15.1.1012.6693
```

If I start the developer command prompt located in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"` I get the following result:

```
C:\Users\user>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 MSBuild Command Prompt
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
C:\Users\user>where msbuild
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

---

1. Why and what is the second path returned after starting the developer command prompt
2. I always use the first path (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`) to call `msbuild` for building C/C++/VC++ Projects. Is this in someway wrong?

Comment: MSBuild was traditionally included with the .NET install.  But that stop scaling when it got to do a lot more jobs, particularly having to build C++ projects at VS2010, supporting WinRT at VS2012 and acquiring a completely new api.  So it was spun-off as a separate product that only comes with a VS install.  The old one was retained for users that relied on MSBuild in their code and to keep home-spun build servers running.  It is unsuitable for building VS2017 or C++ projects, the missing .targets files being the biggest obstacle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS 2017 switched to local copies of msbuild, if you used a VS 2015 command prompt, you would see a different global path.

The `where` command lists all the matching executable files that it finds on the `PATH`, but only the first one will be used by the command prompt when you run an `msbuild` command.

The second `msbuild.exe` you see is part of the .NET Framework - this is the version of MSBuild that was integrated into and shipped as part of the .NET Framework. This version is old compared to the ones installed by recent versions of Visual Studio. But it will likely be continued to be included in .NET Framework for compatibility reasons. It is even able to build a lot of projects that will then use the targets and tasks installed by VS - only project format changes that required changes to MSBuild itself will be incompatible (like the new project format used for .NET Core projects).

You should always use the VS 2017 version of `msbuild.exe` to always get build results consistent with visual studio.