# How to do exe file no root directory?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, msbuild

By default, build path `\debug\x86\` with:

```
db (folder)
log (folder)
*.exe
*.pdb
*.config
```

I want to move *.exe (pdb and config) to my folder `bin` (`\debug\x86\bin`)

I do the next post build script

```
ROBOCOPY "$(TargetDir) " "$(TargetDir)bin\ " *.exe *.config *.pdb /IS /MOVE
```

But when I run the application is crash (or `start` by Visual Studio)

[image]

The project contains other folders. So I want to put the files in different folders.

I want this structure

```
db (folder)
log (folder)
bin (folder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> About why VS threw that error message and you can't start the program
>   in VS:

For C# projects in VS, it has default `Output path`, like what **Larry** suggested above, when we try to simply start or start with debugging the program, VS will call the output xx.exe according to `TargetDir`. Since you use a post-build-event to move the output xx.exe from `$(TargetDir)` to `$(TargetDir)bin`, every time when VS try to start the program, it won't find program since it's actually not in $(TargetDir) path.

Note: The `$(OutputPath)` and `$(TargetDir)` refer to the same path when building by msbuild.

> I want to move *.exe (pdb and config) to my folder bin
>   (\debug\x86\bin)

It's not recommended behavior for C# projects in VS. I assume you may have log and db folders in your current project, if the files in them are set as Content build action and CopyAlways or CopyIfNever, then no matter what output path you set, the output structure is like this:

[image]

There's no need to create a new bin folder at current path and move the `*.exe, *.pdb, *.config` into it. It will affect the normal debug behavior in VS, also it may cause unknown error if the xx.exe depend on the database in db folder. (After changing path, the xx.exe may try to search it in **wrong** path)

Not sure what VS version you use, you can check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902726/different-paths-to-msbuild-in-vs2017). [Msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) is the build engine in VS, and vs use it to build C# projects. You can find its path in your machine and check its typical structure:

```
 --Msbuild.exe
|
 --necessary files
|
 --referenced assemblies
|
 --other folders
```

In summary, using the post-build script will call the crash cause VS won't find the xx.exe. And there is no valid way to get the structure you want, cause the original structure is expected behavior of VS for C# projects. So maybe we can just let it in normal situation it should be.

**Update:**

If now I want to publish the program. Of course now I build the program in release mode. The output structure is:

```
RootDir(name:xxx) ---xx.exe
                  ---xx.config
                  ---log folder
                     ---log file
                  ---text folder
                     ---txt file
                  ---db folder
                     ---db file
```

For your requirement, why not just create a new bin folder and put the xx.exe, xx.config into it. Then rename the Root folder's name, change it manually to this:

```
ProgramName ---bin folder
               ---xx.exe
               ---xx.config
               ---other referenced assemblies
            ---log folder
               ---log file
            ---text folder
               ---txt file
            ---db folder
                ---db file
```

All you need to note is make sure you program can find the required files like [this](https://superuser.com/a/33089). Since you may depend on those files by code, a simple sample is using path in this format: `@"..\text\test.txt"`, the `..` means the above directory. So if you use statement like `@"..\db\database file"`, your program can find the necessary files.

But note this way will affect the noraml debug behavior, so please leave all in normal structure when you're debugging. And use the special structure when you try to release it.

Comment: Thank you, I understand why I get the error from VS. Could you clarify the common actions that other developers do in order to hide the `.exe` file is in a folder not in the root directory. How can they calculate the path to other folders?

Comment: @Viewed What's the special reason you need to hide the .exe in a folder when you're developing and debugging it? I think you only need to do that when you want to publish or share it to others. If so, you can simply move the structure manually to get what you want. Just make sure your .exe can find the needed files.

Comment: @Viewed If you're thinking about how to deploy the program in your expected structure, you can see my update. But if you're debugging your program, which means only you can access the .exe, it could be better if we leave it in normal structure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ROBOCOPY`, change the actual build location of your project.

Go to `Project -> Properties -> Build` and change the output path to `/Debug/x86/bin`.

This should then debug properly.

[VS Docs on Output Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-the-build-output-directory?view=vs-2019)

Comment: This will simply move all the files to the bin folder. I want to have bin log db in the root folder.

Comment: I'm confused, this will only move the built files (eg. .exe and .DLL files) and not the already existing folders.

Comment: So "already existing" are copied from the project. So it will all go to bin.

Comment: Are "log" and "db" built with VS, or are they pre/post build steps? Because if they're not built, they'll just stay in Debug.

Comment: log and db are copy from project (every time during build)

Comment: I try change output path with bin. I get root bin and bin log db inside

Comment: Can't you then just move the folders back from within bin with a post build step?